# Forward declared template specialisation not "filled-in" by actual declaration

Tags: c++, templates

I have multiple `Socket` classes that need to know about `ICommunicationChannel`s for handling incoming messages. The various sockets can use different data types (e.g. CAN frames vs ZMQ messages), but the channel doesn't really care. Therefore, I made the channel a template, which accepts a `ChannelDataType` as a template parameter.

As a rule, I try to forward-declare as much as possible, deferring inclusion of the full definition to the .cpp file if possible. This is what I would like to achieve here as well, however I'm not sure if it's possible.

The problem I'm facing is that the `Socket` implementation (we'll call it `CANSocket`) tries to call a method on the channel, but the compiler says the `ICommunicationChannel` type is incomplete, referencing the forward declaration.

```
/* ICommunicationChannel.h */
template <typename ChannelDataType>
class ICommunicationChannel {
  virtual bool receive(ChannelDataType&) = 0;
}
```

```
/* ICANSocket.h */
template <typename ChannelDataType>
class ICommunicationChannel;

//template <>
//class ICommunicationChannel<can_frame>;
/***
Compiler references this as the incomplete type, if it is included in the code. Without this, it compiles without issue
    "note: declaration of ‘class ICommunicationChannel<can_frame>’ class ICommunicationChannel<can_frame>;"
***/

class ICANSocket {
  virtual void addChannel(ICommunicationChannel<can_frame>*) = 0;
  virtual void receive() = 0;
}
```

```
/* CANSocket.h */
#include "ICANSocket.h"

#include <vector>

class CANSocket : public ICANSocket {
private:
  std::vector<ICommunicationChannel<can_frame>*> m_channels;
public:
  void addChannel(ICommunicationChannel<can_frame>*) final;
  void receive() final;
}
```

```
/* CANSocket.cpp */
#include "CANSocket.h"

#include "ICommunicationChannel.h"

void CANSocket::addChannel(ICommunicationChannel<can_frame>* channel)
{
  m_channels.push_back(channel);
}

void CANSocket::receive()
{
  for (auto channel : m_channels) {
    channel->receive();
    /***
    This is the line that causes the error
        "error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ICommunicationChannel<can_frame>’ channel->receive(frame);"
    ***/
  }
}
```

My question:
Why is the compiler referencing the forward declared type?

EDIT: thanks to @Aconcagua comments, I realised that the cause is my forward declaration of the template specialisation `template<> class ICommunicationChannel`. If I remove that, the code compiles just fine. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Unrelated, but have you noticed that base class and deriving class have different function signatures (once value, once pointer)? `override` keyword helps preventing this kind of error. Additionally, I'd recommend reference instead of pointer (signalling that passing `nullptr` is not acceptable).

Comment: *'deferring inclusion of the full definition to the .cpp'* – which you missed, though...

Comment: You should add virtual destructor to the top most base classes. Otherwise, you cannot correctly delete derived classes via pointer to base – maybe not needed in current scenario, but still a good practice always to follow...

Comment: And you don't need to pre-declare the specialisation. If it exists in the full header, it will be selected, even without having been pre-declared.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for the comments, most of these were just me making mistakes in writing down the example code in this question. I'll edit the code in a moment.

Should I always add a virtual destructor? Sounds like something the compiler should do for me if I don't specify a destructor myself.

Comment: *'Should I always add a virtual destructor?'* – depends... If you don't use your class polymorphically, then no. It would just make the class larger (adding a pointer to a vtable) without any benefit. For polymorphic classes, yes, you should.

Comment: *'compiler should do for me'* – well, *if* you have a virtual function at all... Failing to think up a scenario where that wouldn't be desired (that would be some performance critical scenario at least, guaranteed that none of the objects is deleted by pointer to base, but still relying on polymorphic functions) – but maybe it still exists??? If I ever met, I wouldn't be happy about not being able to turn virtual destructor off...

Comment: So… **why** do you have an explicit specialization for `can_frame` that you never define?

Comment: @DavisHerring What are you referring to exactly? I thought I needed to forward declare the template specialisation to make it work, but turns out I didn't need it. Other than that, I just use the specialised template in places where I expect that specific specialisation, such as the `m_channels` property.

Comment: @Maarten: The declaration beginning with (literally) `template <>`  does not declare that a certain specialization will be *used*; it declares that it will be **different** from the primary template (*e.g.*, because `void` must be handled separately).  Of course, you never supplied the definition for this purportedly different case, so you can’t use it.

Comment: @DavisHerring I thought it was also used to declare that a certain specialisation was going to be required (possibly in another file). Isn't that how you can force the compiler to generate a specific specialisation, because you know it will be used in another .cpp file? (I'm not saying that it's a good approach, I'm just curious about the functionality/syntax)

Comment: @Maarten: You seem to be describing explicit *instantiation* (which looks the same except without the empty `<>`).  You need that only if the code that uses the specialization in question is not in the same translation unit (not file) as the template definition (although it can also be used as a build optimization in certain cases).